# Why does QSettings not store anything?

Tags: qt, qsettings

I want to use `QSettings` to save my window's dimensions so I came up with these two functions to save & load the settings:

```
void MainWindow::loadSettings()
{
    settings = new QSettings("Nothing","KTerminal");
    int MainWidth = settings->value("MainWidth").toInt();
    int MainHeight = settings->value("MainHeight").toInt();
    std::cout << "loadSettings " << MainWidth << "x" << MainHeight << std::endl;
    std::cout << "file: " << settings->fileName().toLatin1().data() << std::endl;
    if (MainWidth && MainHeight)
      this->resize(MainWidth,MainHeight);
    else
      this->resize(1300, 840);
}

void MainWindow::saveSettings()
{
  int MainHeight = this->size().height();
  int MainWidth = this->size().width();

  std::cout << "file: " << settings->fileName().toLatin1().data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "saveSettings " << MainWidth << "x" << MainHeight << std::endl;

  settings->setValue("MainHeight",MainHeight);
  settings->setValue("MainWidth",MainWidth);

}
```

Now, I can see the demensions being extracted in `saveSettings` as expected but no file gets created and hence `loadSettings` will always load 0 only. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QSettings` isn't normally instantiated on the heap.  To achieve the desired effect that you are looking for, follow the [Application Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html) and how it is shown in the `QSettings` documentation.

```
void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings(QCoreApplication::organizationName(), QCoreApplication::applicationName());
    const QByteArray geometry = settings.value("geometry", QByteArray()).toByteArray();
    if (geometry.isEmpty()) {
        const QRect availableGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(this);
        resize(availableGeometry.width() / 3, availableGeometry.height() / 2);
        move((availableGeometry.width() - width()) / 2,
             (availableGeometry.height() - height()) / 2);
    } else {
        restoreGeometry(geometry);
    }
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings(QCoreApplication::organizationName(), QCoreApplication::applicationName());
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
}
```

Also note the use of `saveGeometry()` and `restoreGeometry()`.  Other similarly useful functions for `QWidget` based GUIs are `saveState()` and `restoreState()` (not shown in the above example).

I strongly recommend [the zero parameter constructor of `QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings-4), and to setup the defaults in your `main.cpp`, like so:

```
QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat); // personal preference
qApp->setOrganizationName("Moose Soft");
qApp->setApplicationName("Facturo-Pro");
```

Then when you want to use `QSettings` in any part of your application, you simply do:

```
QSettings settings;

settings.setValue("Category/name", value);
// or
QString name_str = settings.value("Category/name", default_value).toString();
```

`QSettings` in general is highly optimized, and works really well.

Hope that helps.

---

Some other places where I've talked up usage of QSettings:

[Using QSettings in a global static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606306/using-qsettings-in-a-global-static-class)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365937/999943

Comment: Perfect & Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: I think that the reason for `QSettings` not working when allocated on the heap, because it is not destructed (unless `delete` is called). And the destructor of `QSettings` is needed to call its [`sync()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#sync) function.

Comment: Excellent point. The sync function can be manually called to get it to work on the heap.